# AVPlayerViewController: low resolution issue in the first five seconds of streaming .m3u8 video

Tags: swift, m3u8, avplayerviewcontroller

In the first five seconds of streaming an .m3u8 video, the AVPlayerViewController displays a much lower resolution than the rest of the video, even if it is fully buffered, and I return to the first seconds again.

I have tried the following strategies:

- setting the `canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused` attribute of `AVPlayerItem` to true.
- setting the `preferredForwardBufferDuration` attribute of `AVPlayerItem` to 30 seconds.
- using the `AVAsset` method `loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys:completionHandler:)` and creating an `AVPlayerItem` only after ensuring all necessary data has been loaded.
- using KVO on `AVPlayerItem.status` in order to call the `prerollAtRate` method of AVPlayer when its item status is `.readyToPlay`.

This is my setup so far:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://demo.unified-streaming.com/k8s/features/stable/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8")!
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true)
```

First five seconds:
[image]

After five seconds:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's Not AVPlayer problem but it's cause of video

Please check below url and try to see in AVPlayerController

url : https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_fmp4/master.m3u8

Comment: Could you please elaborate why?